# SQL query to SUM up tables from SELECT COUNT statement with UNION

Tags: mysql, count, sum, union

I'm currently trying to sum up the result of an MySQL statement which gives me the amount of rows of several different tables.

I already studied every solution of stackoverflow concerning this matter. Unfortunately I'm not able to figure out the correct syntax for my case.

My working statement with the results **not** summed up:

```
SET @shipmentId=456;
SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Table4 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Table5 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId);
```

In my opinion this should be the nearest to a correct solution but I'm not sure (tried a lot of variants):

```
SET @shipmentId=456;
SELECT SUM(MeasuredValues) FROM
    SELECT(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId) AS MeasuredValues
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId) AS MeasuredValues
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId) AS MeasuredValues
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Table4 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId) AS MeasuredValues
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Table5 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)  AS MeasuredValues) t1;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Already tried the following links:
[StackOverFlow Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577845/sql-query-of-sum-and-count-from-multiple-tables)

[StackOverFlow Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397690/sum-a-pair-of-counts-from-two-tables-based-on-a-time-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply sum up your selects:

```
SET @shipmentId=456;
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
+
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
+
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
+
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table4 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId)
+
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table5 WHERE ShipmentID = @shipmentId);
```